# ios Page View Controller, Single Sided with central Spine

Tags: ios, curl, center, uipageviewcontroller

I'm attempting to create a magazine style app (in horizontal orientation) where the spine is located along the middle.
I have created a pageviewcontroller, set its transition to pagecurl with horizontal orientation. I've also set double sided to NO as i want to display one view per spread.
When the spine is set to location min, it works, however i'd like the spine to be in the middle so when the user turns the page, that current view is divided from it's center.

When i set the spine location to mid, xcode is telling me to make the controller doublesided (so that a view can be seen at each side of the spine) but this is not the effect that i'm after.

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the end I decided to duplicate content in the datasource and mask half the page with a position defined by the odd/even value of the index.
This works fine but it means that I cant have dynamic content running over the spine or odd effects happen.